# C# Dynamic Data Display InjectedPlotter multiple Y Axes

Tags: c#, wpf, plot, linegraph, dynamic-data-display

I have defined a **ChartPlotter** and an **InjectedChartPlotter**. The first one for displaying voltage data and the second one for displaying current data. This data is measured dynamically. My two types of data must share only the X Axis (Time axis). But now, they are sharing all axes (X and Y). I want to define a **specific Y axis for every type of data**. how can I do that ?

My ChartPlotter and my InjectedChartPloatter :

```
<d3:ChartPlotter  x:Name="graphUI" Margin="10,140,10,130">                    
        <d3:InjectedPlotter Name="injGraphUI" >
              <d3:Header Content="Battery data"/>
              <d3:VerticalAxisTitle Content="Voltage"/>
              <d3:HorizontalAxisTitle Content="Time"/>
        </d3:InjectedPlotter>  
</d3:ChartPlotter>
```

I use **ObservableDataSource** objects to create and update my **LineGraphs**